# How to update all JavaFX elements at once?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple javaFX application with some Comboboxes and Textareas.

Combobox1 has all clients from an arraylist. When I delete a client via buttonclick it deletes this client from the list and all other fx elements (like Textareas and comboboxes) should apply this change.

The way I do is to load the clientlist again for each element. For example

clientTextArea.setText(MyClass.getAllclients());

Which is ok when I do this for 2 fx elements but it will become super messy with 10 or 100.
What is the proper way to inform all other related fx elements to reload the clientarray?

Example

```
    public class Worker {

    private String name;

    public Worker(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Work {

    private ArrayList<Worker> workerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addWorker(Worker worker){
            workerList.add(worker);
    }

    public boolean removeWorker(Worker worker) {
        for(Worker work: workerList) {
            if(worker.equals(work)){
                workerList.remove(work);
                return  true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class WorkerFX {

    Work work = new Work();

    @FXML
    private Button add, remove;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Worker> workerComBobox;

    @FXML
    private TextArea workerTextArea;

    @FXML
    private TextField workerTextField;

    public void addWorker(){
       Worker newWorker = new Worker(workerTextField.getText());
       work.addWorker(newWorker);
       workerComBobox.getItems().add(newWorker);
       //now the Textfield schould automaticly also add the Worker too
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list in a for-each loop on itself (your `removeWorker`). In your case it works because you immediate return from the method but this usually ends up with an exception thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your list as an [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) then add a listener to it which contains all the necessary updates to your controls. Something like:

```
ObservableList<SomeClass> myList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

myList.addListener(l -> {
    // do what you need with your controls here   
});
```

If you have 10 or 100 elements you still need to explicitly define their update behaviours. This is unavoidable but by doing this you don't need to worry about calling updates on different sources of changes.

Some controls such as `ComboBox` expose items property, which you can bind to your list instead of updating it in the listener. [Here's a guide to JavaFX property binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm). Either way you still need to explicitly define the update behaviour for each control somewhere.

Comment: Thanks alot. I get this concept but I have another problem. My clientlist is a field in my ClientHandler class. How can I bind this list to the observable so that every change of the observable list is a direct change of the client list in my ClientHandler class?

Comment: Use [bindBidirectional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindBidirectional-javafx.beans.property.Property-javafx.beans.property.Property-)

Comment: With bindBidirectional I can bind all the textpropertys and make them all change when I change one but is there a way for the Observable list to link it to my list in my other class? Does it make any sense?

Comment: @QickdmGdombu Can you edit your question to include an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: done  I hope its more clear now sorry. I want that everytime something changes for example a new worker ges added or anotherone gets removed in the Worker arraylist, both textarea and combobox should update or in other words only show whats in the worker Arraylist

Comment: For that case I don't think it's possible to use a binding, you need to handle the change in the listener